# Receiving error from helicontech of "Any JDK not found"

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, helicontech, heliconzoo

I have try many times to install one of Helicon Zoo packages (Jetty of Tomcat) according to [this article](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/deploying-java-servlet-applications-on-windows-with-iis/).

But I'm getting same error in the title always. Because so many times to uninstall and install jdk, I thought that I might have broken something.

So reinstall Windows and first thing first installed jdk and try and the result is same.

> CAQuietExec64:  Any JDK not found

Answer (score 0):

Helicon Zoo version mentioned in this article is deprecated. Please try using open source version of Zoo from here: https://github.com/helicontech/zoo/releases
You will still need to install JDK manually as Oracle prohibit installation of JDK by other programs.